# How to calculate the derivative of f(net)=tanh(net) in c++

Tags: c++, neural-network, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need to implement a Multilayer Perceptron using Levenberg  - Marquardt algorithm. To find slope of activation function (tanh), derivative of tanhx = sec^2 hx haas to be calculated. Is there any library function in c++ to calculate sec^2 hx.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The standard library gives hyperbolic sine, cosine and tangent functions; other hyperbolic functions can be derived from these:

```
#include <cmath>

double sech2(double x) {
    double sh = 1.0 / std::cosh(x);   // sech(x) == 1/cosh(x)
    return sh*sh;                     // sech^2(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those led here by Google... it would be safer to use tanh(x) instead of cosh(x) to avoid overflow.

```
#include <cmath>
double sech2(const double x) {
    double th = tanh(x); // tanh(x) \in (-1,1); cosh(x) \in (1,inf)
    return 1.0 - th*th; // sech^2(x) = 1 - tanh^2(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
inline double sec_sq(double x) {
    double cosx = std::cos(x);
    return 1.0 / (cosx*cosx);
}
```